# sql to read n number of rows and display in fixed number of columns

Tags: sql, pivot

We are currently using SQL2005. I have a SQL table that stores serial numbers in a single column. Thus 10 000 serial numbers mean 10 000 rows. When these are printed on an invoice, one serial number per row is being printed due to how the information is stored. We currently use the built-in invoice in our ERP system but will change to SSRS if I can get the printing of serials sorted.

How can I read the serial numbers and display it (either in a view or sp) maybe **10 at a time per row**. Thus if I am reading 18 serials it will be two rows (1st row with 10 serials and 2nd row with 8 serials). If I am reading 53 serials, it will be 6 rows. Getting this right will cut down on the paper needed for invoice printing to roughly a tenth of what is currently required!

Just to be clear...the serials are currently are stored and print like this :

```
Ser1  
Ser2  
Ser3  
Ser4  
Ser5
```

I would prefer them to print like this :

```
Ser1 Ser2 Ser3 Ser4 Ser5 Ser6 Ser7 Ser8 Ser9 Ser10  
Ser11 Ser12 Ser13 Ser14 Ser15 Ser16....etc
```

Thanks

Comment: When I had to do something similar a few years ago I used a [CLR Stored Procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5czye81z(v=vs.90).aspx). Shelling out the processing to C#/VB sped things up no end. It was also easier to change the program and parameters that it required to get different results (e.g. Number of items on a line, adding commas etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` to assign a unique number to each row.  That allows you to `group by rn / 10`, giving you groups of 10 rows.

Here's an example for 3 instead of 10 rows:

```
select  max(case when rn % 3 = 0 then serialno end) as sn1
,       max(case when rn % 3 = 1 then serialno end) as sn2
,       max(case when rn % 3 = 2 then serialno end) as sn3
from    (
        select  row_number() over (order by serialno) -1 as rn
        ,       serialno
        from    @t
        ) as SubQueryAlias
group by
        rn / 3
```

[See it working at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c07ca/1/0)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've modified for 10 serial numbers in a row and it works perfectly.

Comment: This was a simple solution to what seemed like a complex problem...thanks again!